# Stackengine and missing $ issue

Tags: math-mode, stackengine

Using stackengine I want to create a doublestruck nabla symbol, but I run into missing $ issue.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\nablads}{\stackinset{c}{0.4pt}{t}{0.05ex}{\rule{.4pt}{1.1ex}%
                      \mspace{2mu}\rule{.4pt}{1.0ex}}{\nabla{}}}

\begin{document}
$\nablads$
\end{document}
```

This produces the typical "Missing $ inserted" error (twice), but I cant seem able to get rid of it (by adding \esuremath or $s on various places). Can you improve my code so the error does not occure or suggest some workaround?

EDIT: In comments to the answer a comparatively better way to achieve doublestruck nabla is suggested. This puts the existence of this (admittedly weak) question in question :D. If requested, I will remove it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `$\mspace{2mu}$` and `$\nabla$` should do.

Comment: Perhaps you should also explain what exactly you are trying to do here. Perhaps tehre are better ways.

Comment: @daleif Please consider it a genuine question, not me being mean. In what department is the declaration of intention "I want to create a doublestruck nabla symbol" lacking? I could specify "vertically double-struck nabla", but that is the best I can do without suggesting any specific method (which might limit someone trying to come up with a better way of achieving the goal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would see the same from `\mbox{\mspace{2mu}}` you could use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\nablads}{\stackinset{c}{0.4pt}{t}{0.05ex}{\rule{.4pt}{1.1ex}%
                      $\mspace{2mu}$\rule{.4pt}{1.0ex}}{$\nabla$}}

\begin{document}
$\nablads$
\end{document}
```

but it's not really clear what the intention is here I suspect a much simpler definition would be possible.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I was too focused on the \nabla symbol and did not realize there are other math elements. @David would you like to share the simpler definition of "vertically doublestruck nabla" you had in mind?

Comment: @P.L. perhaps `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$\mathrlap{\mspace{5mu}\rule[.5ex]{.5pt}{1ex}}\nabla\mathllap{\rule[.5ex]{.5pt}{1ex}\mspace{5mu}}$
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you, I will actually use what you suggested since it avoids usage of aditional package and offers the same customizability.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options...

1. As mentioned by others, delimit math expressions such as `\mspace{}` and `\nabla` with `$`
2. Use `\ensurestackMath{}` to force `stackengine` to locally set its arguments in math mode
3. Use `\stackMath` to globally set `stackengine` to employ math mode for its arguments.

Here is the MWE.  All three techniques are shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\nablads}{\stackinset{c}{0.4pt}{t}{0.05ex}{\rule{.4pt}{1.1ex}%
                      $\mspace{2mu}$\rule{.4pt}{1.0ex}}{$\nabla$}}
\newcommand{\nnablads}{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{0.4pt}{t}{0.05ex}{\rule{.4pt}{1.1ex}%
                      \mspace{2mu}\rule{.4pt}{1.0ex}}{\nabla}}}
\newcommand{\nnnablads}{\stackinset{c}{0.4pt}{t}{0.05ex}{\rule{.4pt}{1.1ex}%
                      \mspace{2mu}\rule{.4pt}{1.0ex}}{\nabla}}

\begin{document}
$\nablads$% $ delimiters around \mspace and \nabla

$\nnablads$% use \ensurestackMath for local application

\stackMath\nnnablads% globally set \stackMath
\end{document}
```

[image]